# Where is Xamarin.Essentials.Locale properties?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, localization

I found that there is [Xamarin.Essentials.Locale](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.locale?view=xamarin-essentials) class exists in MS Docs as well as in Xamarin.Essentials v1.7.3 that is used by my app. When I go to definition of Locale class, it shows the properties that I need, such as Country and Language.

However in my code, there is no way to access those properties through Locale class or create Local class object.

Is there a way to get Country and Language full names in Xamarin Forms 5 application? I am looking for the simplest solution that will work cross-platform.

[image]

Comment: why don't you use the .NET Core Locale classes?

Comment: @Jason as I understand it needs to implement DependecyService for each platform, isn't it? I believe there should be simpler solution.

Comment: You haven't actually explained what it is you want to do.  But .NET Core classes are cross platform.

Comment: I explained that want to retrieve Country and Language names of user's device. I know that net.core is cross-platform, but as I see it is needed to fill System.Globalization.CultureInfo object inside each platform

Comment: try `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`

Comment: thanks for the tip. It works close to what I wanted to achieve, however returns "Russia" as a country, but my device is registered for Ukraine and Ukrainian AppStore. This native iOS call returns correct result - NSLocale.CurrentLocale.GetCountryCodeDisplayName(NSLocale.CurrentLocale.CountryCode);